# Function to return SQL query and display result in a new Form's datagrid view

Tags: sql, vb.net, function, datagrid, datareader

I'm stuck! I have the function below, which needs to return a table and display it on a new Form's datagrid. If I run the query in SSMS it returns a table. But I don't know how to display it in a datagrid. Any tips will be appreciated.

```
Public Shared Function verificaschimb(ByVal schimb As String, data As DateTime) As Integer
    Dim verificare As New SqlDataReader
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SVNAV;Initial Catalog=NAV_Vermorel_Live;User ID=sa;Password=1234")
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select COUNT(DISTINCT [Cod Angajat]), [Cod Angajat], [Nume], [Timp declarat] FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieVE] WHERE (sum([Timp declarat] <8 AND cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) As DateTime) = @data2) And ([Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "' GROUP BY [Nume], [Cod Angajat], [Timp declarat] HAVING sum([Timp declarat])<8", con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2", data)
            con.Open()
            verificare = cmd.ExecuteReader
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If con IsNot Nothing Then
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then                    '
                con.Close()
            End If
            con.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
    Return verificare
End Function
```

Comment: nevermind. i think it is impossible to do it inside a function. but i still need some help at the displaying in a datagrid part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to bind to DataGridView is using a DataTable. Your function returns integer which can't be used as data source.

I made some changes to your function to return DataTable and some lines of code for databinding:

```
    Public Shared Function verificaschimb(ByVal schimb As String, data As DateTime) As DataTable
        Dim verificare As New DataTable
        Dim con As New SqlConnection
        Try
            con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=SVNAV;Initial Catalog=NAV_Vermorel_Live;User ID=sa;Password=1234")
            Using cmd As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select COUNT(DISTINCT [Cod Angajat]), [Cod Angajat], [Nume], [Timp declarat] FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieVE] WHERE (sum([Timp declarat] <8 AND cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) As DateTime) = @data2) And ([Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "' GROUP BY [Nume], [Cod Angajat], [Timp declarat] HAVING sum([Timp declarat])<8", con)
                cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2", data)
                con.Open()
                cmd.Fill(verificare)
                con.Close()
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        Finally
            If con IsNot Nothing Then
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then                    '
                    con.Close()
                End If
                con.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
        Return verificare
    End Function

    Public Sub MainCode()
        Dim dt As DataTable = verificaschimb("test", Now.Date)
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please help me into one more matter? The sql query doesnt return what I want, and i dont know what i do wrong. i need to return each unique id for wich the sum of all previous entries for that id in the column [Timp declarat] < 8.

Comment: Supposing that your field 'nume' is the wanted 'ID' this is the statement which gives you unique ID and Sum(Timp declarat):

SELECT nume,sum([Timp declarat]) FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieVE]
WHERE cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) As DateTime) 
= @data2 
And [Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "' 
GROUP BY nume 
HAVING sum([Timp declarat])<8

Comment: I know i shouldnt reply with +1 or thanks, but THANKS man! works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer here:
[Filling a DataGridView from SQLReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151641/filling-a-datagridview-from-sqlreader)

You can't bind a datareader directly to a datagridview in WinForms. Instead you could load a datatable with your reader and assign the datatable to the datasource of the DataGridView

```
Dim dt = new DataTable()
dt.Load(reader)
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String MyConString = "Data Source=SVNAV;Initial Catalog=NAV_Vermorel_Live;User ID=sa;Password=1234";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select COUNT(DISTINCT [Cod Angajat]), [Cod Angajat], [Nume], [Timp declarat] FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieVE] WHERE (sum([Timp declarat] <8 AND cast(CONVERT(varchar(8), Data, 112) As DateTime) = @data2) And ([Schimb] = '" & ProceseazaSCH(Now()) & "' GROUP BY [Nume], [Cod Angajat], [Timp declarat] HAVING sum([Timp declarat])<8", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2", data)
        conn.Open();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dataTable);
        GridVIew.DataSource = dataTable;
        GridVIew.DataBind();
```

please try this code